# What's the meaning of `@@ -6,7 +6,6 @@` in gitk's diff panel?

Tags: git, gitk

I am confused about the `@@ -a,b +c,d @@` in gitk's diff panel, and i find it will change with `lines of context`, so can any kind people tell me what does it really mean?

Comment: This is standard unified `diff` format and not specific to `git` (let alone `gitk`). Read [the documentation.](https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-format)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+diff+output